# JavaScript, remove click after onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1500);"

Tags: javascript

I have a question. Currently I added a onload autoclick for the animation to happen once page is loaded. But when i click anywhere on the page after animation has loaded, then the animation reverts back to the beginning and I don't want that to happen. I would like the click to completely disappear after autoclick has loaded. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function autoClick(){
        document.getElementById('curtain-container-main').click();
      }
  </script>

  <style>
    body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.stage {
  background: #fff;
  width: 560px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  border: 15px solid #333;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 11px #aaa, inset 1px 3px 6px #ccc;
  padding: 1em 0 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.stage-content {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.stage-content:after {
  /* content: "Achievement Unlock"; */
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.curtain-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-panel {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain-panel .curtain {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 2s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain-panel .curtain:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  text-align: center;
  /* width: 200%; */
  width: 175%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
}

.left-curtain {
  /* background-image: url("img/Logo-Curtain-Left-Half.png"); */
  background-image: url("https://teqcube.com/logo-entrance-test/img/test-left-logo.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position-x: right;
}

.curtain-panel .left-curtain:before {
  left: 0;
}

.right-curtain {
  /* background-image: url("img/Logo-Curtain-Right-Half.png"); */
  background-image: url("https://teqcube.com/logo-entrance-test/img/test-right-logo.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position-x: left;
}

.curtain-panel .right-curtain:before {
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-panel .curtain:after {
  content: "";
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 12px,
    #fff 13px
  );
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-trigger {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.curtain-trigger:checked ~ .left-curtain {
  /* transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 2em)); */
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 0em));
}

.curtain-trigger:checked ~ .right-curtain {
  /* transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2em)); */
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 0em));
}

  </style>

</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1500);">
  
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="stage-content">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Three equal width columns</h1>
        <p>Note: Try to add a new div with class="col" inside the row class - this will create three equal-width columns.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <label class="curtain-container">
      <div class="curtain-panel">
        <input type="checkbox" class="curtain-trigger" id="curtain-container-main"/>
        <div class="left-curtain curtain">
          <!-- <img src="img/Logo-Curtain-Left-Half.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"> -->
        </div>
        <div class="right-curtain curtain">
          <!-- <img src="img/Logo-Curtain-Right-Half.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the cursor to disappear you can just set the cursor property to none inside your click function.

```
function autoClick(){
        document.getElementById('curtain-container-main').click();
        //Disable checkbox
        $('.curtain-trigger').prop("disabled", true);
        //Other options to disable checkbox in case the above doesn't work
        //$('.curtain-trigger').prop("checked", false);
        //$('.curtain-trigger').attr("disabled", true);
      }
```

Comment: I don't want the cursor to dissapear, I basically need the checkbox to be disabled after auto click has happened. Because if cursor dissapears, then the user won't be able to navigate and click on the site with no cursor. The opening animation should only play once onload. From there onwards everything has to be normal.

Comment: Oh that's pretty simple. You can use jQuery or JS to disable the checkbox. Check the edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your `function autoClick()`, do:

```
$( "#curtain-container-main" ).one( "click", function() {
  $("#curtain-container-main").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: I have tried this thank you Feedy, but there should be no click involved. Onload autoclick, and then the checkbox needs to be disabled after onload. I know it's possible, but not sure how to get the effect.

Comment: Following this code, can you not set the `disabled` property of the checkbox to true after the click is done?

Comment: @Dane See my edited answer, is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I have added disabled property on your input element after first click call. Here is the working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function autoClick(){
      var elem = document.getElementById('curtain-container-main');
        elem.click();
        elem.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
      }
      
      
  </script>

  <style>
    body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.stage {
  background: #fff;
  width: 560px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  border: 15px solid #333;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 11px #aaa, inset 1px 3px 6px #ccc;
  padding: 1em 0 3em;
  position: relative;
}

.stage-content {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.stage-content:after {
  /* content: "Achievement Unlock"; */
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.curtain-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-panel {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain-panel .curtain {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 2s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curtain-panel .curtain:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  text-align: center;
  /* width: 200%; */
  width: 175%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
}

.left-curtain {
  /* background-image: url("img/Logo-Curtain-Left-Half.png"); */
  background-image: url("https://teqcube.com/logo-entrance-test/img/test-left-logo.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position-x: right;
}

.curtain-panel .left-curtain:before {
  left: 0;
}

.right-curtain {
  /* background-image: url("img/Logo-Curtain-Right-Half.png"); */
  background-image: url("https://teqcube.com/logo-entrance-test/img/test-right-logo.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-position-x: left;
}

.curtain-panel .right-curtain:before {
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-panel .curtain:after {
  content: "";
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at 10px -5px,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 12px,
    #fff 13px
  );
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.curtain-trigger {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.curtain-trigger:checked ~ .left-curtain {
  /* transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 2em)); */
  transform: translateX(calc(-100% + 0em));
}

.curtain-trigger:checked ~ .right-curtain {
  /* transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2em)); */
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 0em));
}
  </style>

</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1500);">
  
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="stage-content">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Three equal width columns</h1>
        <p>Note: Try to add a new div with class="col" inside the row class - this will create three equal-width columns.</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <label class="curtain-container">
      <div class="curtain-panel">
        <input type="checkbox" class="curtain-trigger" id="curtain-container-main"/>
        <div class="left-curtain curtain">
          <!-- <img src="img/Logo-Curtain-Left-Half.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"> -->
        </div>
        <div class="right-curtain curtain">
          <!-- <img src="img/Logo-Curtain-Right-Half.png" alt="" style="width: 100%;"> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```